# Fixed div responsive in css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-position, antd

I am making a sidebar using react with antd.

```
<Sider
  style={{
    overflow: "auto",
    height: "100vh",
    position: "fixed",
    left: 0
  }}
>
  <div className="logo" />
  <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={["4"]}>
    <Menu.Item key="1" icon={<UserOutlined />}>
      nav 1
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="2" icon={<VideoCameraOutlined />}>
      nav 2
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="3" icon={<UploadOutlined />}>
      nav 3
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="4" icon={<BarChartOutlined />}>
      nav 4
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="5" icon={<CloudOutlined />}>
      nav 5
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="6" icon={<AppstoreOutlined />}>
      nav 6
    </Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
  <div class="avatar">
    <img
      style={{
        width: "60px",
        height: "60px",
        lineHeight: "60px",
        fontSize: "30px"
      }}
      src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2922/2922510.png"
      alt="profile"
    />
  </div>
</Sider>
```

Here I have included a div at the bottom of menu as user profile.

```
  <div class="avatar">
    <img
      style={{
        width: "60px",
        height: "60px",
        lineHeight: "60px",
        fontSize: "30px"
      }}
      src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2922/2922510.png"
      alt="profile"
    />
  </div>
```

In normal view it is working fine but when we zoom in, the profile image overlays on the other menu items.

Tried including the value in `vh` for height and `vw` for width but that doesn't help.

So how to make this profile image as responsive while **zoom in** and **zoom out** of the page?

Tried all the below given solutions but I couldn't achieve the expected result. Kindly please help me as I am stuck here for too long. Big thanks in advance.

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit Fixed Sider - antd@4.18.2 (forked)]

Comment: this issue is similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995249/is-it-possible-to-make-a-fixed-position-div-responsive

Comment: @NajmiehSadatSafarabadi I have tried setting `vh` for height and `vw` for width but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.avatar {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
  
  .ant-layout-sider-children {
    display: flex;
    flex - direction: column;
}
  
  .ant-menu {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}

.ant-layout-sider {
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: After implementing this code, the profile image has been cut at the bottom. Forked sandbox with your code https://codesandbox.io/s/fixed-sider-antd-4-18-2-forked-e7ypn . Please compare the profile image with the sandbox link in question.

Comment: Even after implementing the above edited code, I get the same result still.

Answer (score 0):

First. I would avoid inline style for the image. Try to use CSS instead.
You gave the Avatar object a fixed position which means it's going to be kind of sticky and go over other elements. On your CSS you can use media queries like that:

```
@media (max-width: 767.98px) { 
.avatar img{
position:relative;
width:30px;
height:30px;
}
}
```

It's going to change it on mobile devices But this will give it a relative position off course

Comment: Tried adding the above code here https://codesandbox.io/s/fixed-sider-antd-4-18-2-forked-qzbp1 but still image overlays on the menu items on zoom in.

Comment: It was just an example. If you give the .avatar class relative position it would be easier. try this     .avatar{
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
  .avatar img {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
  }
} 
media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  
  .avatar img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
  }
}

Comment: After implementing the above one here https://codesandbox.io/s/fixed-sider-antd-4-18-2-forked-3hd2q, it makes the profile image move up (under last nav) .. The profile avatar image needs to stay at bottom.

Comment: I hope I get what you want here. If you want it to stay on the bottom always you need to use position:absolute; but it still going to behave as fixed. means pop over other elements. Try it and see if it gets better

Comment: Could you please fork the above given sandbox and update the solution if possible? My question is that I have a user profile image at bottom and on zoom in and zoom out it needs to be responsive and that is the requirement.